# Return pound-ounces instead of decimal pounds when using Measurement

Tags: swift, units-of-measurement, measurement

Is it possible to have `Measurement` return `2lb 8oz` instead of `2.5 lb` when `2.5` is provided as the value as in the example below?

```
var pounds = Measurement(value:2.5, unit: UnitMass.pounds)// outputs 2.5 lb
// desired output 2 lb 8 oz
```

EDIT:
Just to put it in context, here is what I'm trying to do. I'm saving three different measurement unit types, `lb`, `kg`, and `ea` in a decimal format, and I would like to use `Measurement` for displaying the values retrieved from the database, based on the unit type. I know I can do this myself with a helper class but I want to start using `Measurement` as much as possible.

Comment: You would need 2 measurements. Truncate the first and use the remainder for the second.

Comment: Ah ok, it may be easier to just implement my own method myself. So, it looks like the main purpose of `Measurement` is for easy conversions between units. If my assumption is correct, I'm not sure if displaying `2.5 lb` makes too much sense since most people want to see 2lb 8oz, not a decimal equivalent. I guess I'm asking myself, where would someone want to display `2.5 lb` in a user interface?

Comment: I don’t think I have seen 2lb 8oz on many things, this is one of those preference things I think IMO 2.3 lb of something is much better than 2lb 4.8 oz. Or should you go down to tablespoons? Teaspoons?

Comment: Hmm, very good point but in my case, the decimal value will be originated by a UI that lets the user only select integer values from 1-15 as the ounces, 1/16= .0625, 2/16= .125, 3/16= .1875, 4/16= .250, etc. so in theory 2.3 will never be an option, but you pointed out a very valid point that I didn't think about until now, makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Got it, if you are going to stick to imperial measurements only. Think about localization, If you end up supporting other languages sticking to a strictly imperial UI will be very limiting. Essentially your only mark will be people born and raised in the US.

Comment: You should also use a `MeasurementFormatter` to format a `Measurement` value for displaying to a user, you shouldn't rely on its (debug)description.

Comment: It is maddening that the Measurement class won't output Imperial/US customary units as pound/ounce or foot/inch. That seems like an obvious and necessary feature for formatted output of measurement units, just like DateFormatters will display in all kinds of different formats. (Granted, US customary units are a hot mess, but that's a different topic.)

Comment: It looks like the Measurement for "width" will output feet and inches if you specify "person" measurements in US customary units with a US locale. Seems like there should be a way to get pounds and ounces for mass somehow then.

Comment: @loremipsum - No, I will also be supporting Kilograms. See my edited question.  Thank you all for your input.

Comment: @DávidPásztor  - I'll look into `MeasurementFormatter`. Thanks.

Comment: The solution doesn't change, you need 2 measurements to present as you want it (or maybe formatter as mentioned above). Doing this is without "truncating" is the best part of measurement. truncating adds a whole other layer, 1 oz is 28.75 grams and a 2.22 kg are a pound? the decimals would become too much (IMO), It is much easier to just let the user pick their units and "auto-convert" when they change the unit value if needed. In SwiftUI it can be a little tricky because Measurement is a class that isn't an ObservableObject but workable.

Comment: You can always create your own formatter too, it might be a way to manage all this without cluttering.

Comment: Here is what I think I will be doing, I'll have a `Picker` so the user selects `lb` and `oz` or `kg` and `g` and right before saving the value convert it to pound-decimal or kilograms-decimal respectably. For reading it back, I will be getting the decimal value and convert it back to `lb/oz` or `kg/g`, e.g. `if item.UnitType.pounds{formatDecimalPoundsAsString(decimal:Double)}`. And for any calculation or conversion I'll be using the decimal value straight from the database in `Measurement`.

Comment: To separate the whole number and the fraction from the decimal I would probably use, `modf(decimal).0` and `modf(decimal).1` or  the components(separateBy) method, `let numbers = String(decimal).components(separateBy: ["."])` then get each number individually like so,  `numbers[0]` and  `numbers[1]`